# Fit full thumbnails in a masonry display

Tags: css, masonry

I'm getting thumbnail images cut off horizontally here:
https://magicitems.org/#/artworks

I'm assuming this is a css fix, but nothing I've tried works. The relevant css code for the masonry is here:

```
.my-masonry-grid {
  display: -webkit-box; /* Not needed if autoprefixing */
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* Not needed if autoprefixing */
  object-fit: contain;
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: -16px;
}

.my-masonry-grid_column {
  padding-left: 16px; /* gutter size */
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

.my-masonry-grid_column > div {
  /* change div to reference your elements you put in <Masonry> */
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

That's referenced by the following react code, in case that helps:

```
  const artworkGrid = (
    <Masonry
      breakpointCols={breakpointColumnsObj}
      className="my-masonry-grid"
      columnClassName="my-masonry-grid_column"
    >
      {!isLoading
        ? items.map((m, idx) => {
            const id = m.pubkey.toBase58();
            return (
              <Link to={`/art/${id}`} key={idx}>
                <ArtCard
                  key={id}
                  pubkey={m.pubkey}
                  preview={false}
                  height={250}
                  width={250}
                />
              </Link>
            );
          })
        : [...Array(10)].map((_, idx) => <CardLoader key={idx} />)}
    </Masonry>
  );
```

Comment: Seems like using `background-image` will be easier. Then you can set `background-size` as `contain`.

Comment: If I use [background-image] in the css do I have to change the js also? Tricky thing here is that each element is the masonry grid is pulling a separate image, so the css can't refer to something static.

Comment: I found what was causing this problem. Just posted an answer : )

Comment: Awesome. If your problem was solved, please accept the answer by pressing the green check button.

Comment: Btw you went above and beyond by fixing code that I hadn’t even displayed… so generous and cool!

Comment: I will click the green button - I have a quick question in case you l know an easy fix. Do you know how to size the masonry box to fit the vertical size of the image? I think this would right size each box to fit the image, rather than getting borders depending on the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: Remove the `height` attribute or use `height: auto;`. That will do the trick

Comment: Fantastic! Looks so great!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `<img>` tag that the thumbnails are displayed, `object-fit: cover` is applied.

Change that to

```
object-fit: contain;
```

And it will stay inside the container.

> The replaced content is scaled to maintain its aspect ratio while fitting within the element’s content box. The entire object is made to fill the box, while preserving its aspect ratio, so the object will be "letterboxed" if its aspect ratio does not match the aspect ratio of the box.

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Here's what happens:

**BEFORE**
[image: Image is cropped]

**AFTER**
[image: Image looks fine]